# Update Stripe Payment Amount

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, stripe-payments, payment

I'm attempting to have two stripe payment amounts on a one page application. The user has 5 minutes to purchase the item at a sale price. I then need to be able to update the price to a different amount. I tried to simply create two stripe forms but you're not able to have more than one on a page per my understanding. How would I go about doing this?

My stripe set-up:

```
var token = req.body.stripeToken; // Using Express
var charge = stripe.charges.create({
  amount: 749,
  currency: "usd",
  description: "Example charge",
  source: token,
```

How would I change the "amount?"

Comment: You would create a Checkout experience where you supply the `amount`-argument to Checkout with an outside input, then pass that amount to your backend and replace your hardcoded `794` with the value you pass.

Answer (score 0):

If you had a `<input type="hidden" name="chosen_amount" id="chosen_amount" />`

And use Javascript to change the value of the hidden field on click of the button then you can access the amount on the backend with `var amount = req.body.chose_amount;`